# Adding Existing Index in a table (which is made of two fields) as Primary Index? ax 2012

Tags: primary-key, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, surrogate-key, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have an index TestIndex in my table with two fields: Code1 and Code2.
Index Properties: Allow Duplicates:No,  AlternateKey: Yes
Field Properties: Mandatory:Yes AllowEdit:No

When I got to Table Properties PrimaryIndex:SurrogateKey.
I want to change this PrimaryIndex to TestIndex. 
But when I click on DropDown it's not showing TestIndex value.
When I enter manually TestIndex and click enter its showing TestIndex.
But when I click on the dropdown I am not able to see testIndex.

Why?
The manual thing which I have done is wrong or correct?

How can I get TestIndex in dropdown of primaryIndex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Table Keys: Surrogate, Alternate, Replacement, Primary, and Foreign](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh812105.aspx)

> A table can have several alternate keys. Any one alternate key can switch to being the primary key, if the alternate key is comprised of only one field.

Comment: But my Index has TwoFields. So i dont know how can i get that in lookup of primaryIndex of table?

Comment: You can, but only if you use an old style table. This property is only exposed in the XPO. It is not meant to be used for new tables!